# object doesn't support this property in jquery mvc4

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery", "~/bundles/jqueryui", "~/bundles/WorkbenchScripts")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/WorkbenchCss")
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        checkSpecialChars('#txtCreateSet');
        $('#btnCancelSet').click(function (e) {
            window.close();
        });
    });


    //this function is used to allow only specific characters in function
    function checkSpecialChars(textboxID) {
        debugger;

        return textboxID.each
            (
                function () {
                    var allowedChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
                    allowedChars += "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
                    allowedChars += "0123456789";
                    allowedChars += " "; //Space
                    //Check if try to specifying allowed special characters for Name fields
                    allowedChars += "-_";
                    //on keypress
                    $(textboxID).keypress(function (e) {
                        var keyUniCode = !e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode;

                        var charValue = String.fromCharCode(keyUniCode);

                        if (keyUniCode != 13) {
                            if (allowedChars.indexOf(charValue) == -1)
                                e.preventDefault();
                        }
                    });
                    //On paste
                    $(textboxID).bind('paste', function (e) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            var newText = textboxID.val();
                            $.each(newText, function (i) {
                                if (allowedChars.indexOf(newText.charAt(i)) == -1)
                                { textboxID.val(textboxID.val().replace(newText.charAt(i), '')); }
                            });
                        }, 1);
                    });
                }
            );
            };
</script>






<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
              @Html.Label("Create Set")
            </td>
            <td>
             @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SetName, new { id = "txtCreateSet" })
            </td>
        </tr>
<table>
```

In the above code i am getting the error "object does not support this property",i am using MVC4  and here i have written the code in mvc view that in the textbox only characters allowed are 0-9 a-z A-Z - _ and space characters.Where i am doing wrong?can anyone help me to get the desired solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you're passing your function the selector string and **not** the objects.

See here:

```
checkSpecialChars('#txtCreateSet');
```

That means that when you do the following, you will get that error because there's no `each` method on a string:

```
return textboxID.each
```

Try this, passing the jQuery object:

```
checkSpecialChars($('#txtCreateSet'));
```

Comment: Thanx a lot,could u tell me what is difference between checkSpecialChars('#txtCreateSet') and checkSpecialChars($('#txtCreateSet'))?

Comment: Wrapping it in `$()` means that you're telling jQuery to go and get everything that matches your string selector. In your case, get everything with an ID of `txtCreateSet` (`#` means search on ID). Without the `$()` is literally just the string of characters `#txtCreateSet`